# How do I make recursive functions work in this particular Python script?

Tags: python, xml, recursion, elementtree, findall

I'm working on this project using Python, in which the first step involves parsing some data from an xml file. The xml files that gets generated for this task however, create too many attributes and the data needs to be consolidated somehow.

Anyway, I think the first thing I need to go is get recursive functions working. I've been using this website (https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-xml-elementtree) as a guide along with various other Googlings in order to edit the xml file. However, the **findall** function doesn't seem to work in the same way in my script as everyone suggests on the internet. So I'm wondering where I'm going wrong.

Here is the xml:

```
<session
    beginTime="2020-04-02T14:49:20"
    halSerialNumber="22F-0050"
    testMode="Remote"
    userName="Martin">
    <appliance overallResult="Passed" serialNumber="015055540215174421VPX4B6I1079">
        <test_set testState="Passed">
            <test
                lowerLimitMilliohms="0.00"
                name="Earth Bond 50Hz - CONTROL COVER"
                numTests="1"
                startConditions="StartKey"
                targetOutputAmps="25.0"
                timeHoldSeconds="2.0"
                timeRampDownSeconds="0.0"
                timeRampUpSeconds="0.0"
                type="EarthBond50"
                upperLimitMilliohms="200.00"
            />
            <test_result
                appliedOutputAmps="25.0"
                earthBondResistanceMilliohms="84.0"
                testDurationSeconds="2.00"
                testState="Passed"
                timeOfTest="2020-04-02T14:50:07"
            />
        </test_set>
        <test_set testState="Passed">
            <test
                lowerLimitMilliohms="0.00"
                name="Earth Bond 50Hz - CONTROL COVER"
                numTests="1"
                startConditions="StartKey"
                targetOutputAmps="25.0"
                timeHoldSeconds="2.0"
                timeRampDownSeconds="0.0"
                timeRampUpSeconds="0.0"
                type="EarthBond50"
                upperLimitMilliohms="200.00"
            />
            <test_result
                appliedOutputAmps="25.0"
                earthBondResistanceMilliohms="84.0"
                testDurationSeconds="2.00"
                testState="Passed"
                timeOfTest="2020-04-02T14:50:14"
            />
        </test_set>
        <test_set testState="Passed">
            <test
                lowerLimitMilliohms="0.00"
                name="Earth Bond 50Hz - CONTROL COVER"
                numTests="1"
                startConditions="StartKey"
                targetOutputAmps="25.0"
                timeHoldSeconds="2.0"
                timeRampDownSeconds="0.0"
                timeRampUpSeconds="0.0"
                type="EarthBond50"
                upperLimitMilliohms="200.00"
            />
            <test_result
                appliedOutputAmps="25.0"
                earthBondResistanceMilliohms="85.0"
                testDurationSeconds="2.00"
                testState="Passed"
                timeOfTest="2020-04-02T14:50:19"
            />
        </test_set>
        <test_set testState="Passed">
            <test
                lowerLimitMilliohms="0.00"
                name="Earth Bond 50Hz - CONTROL COVER"
                numTests="1"
                startConditions="StartKey"
                targetOutputAmps="25.0"
                timeHoldSeconds="2.0"
                timeRampDownSeconds="0.0"
                timeRampUpSeconds="0.0"
                type="EarthBond50"
                upperLimitMilliohms="200.00"
            />
            <test_result
                appliedOutputAmps="25.0"
                earthBondResistanceMilliohms="86.0"
                testDurationSeconds="2.00"
                testState="Passed"
                timeOfTest="2020-04-02T14:50:24"
            />
        </test_set>
        <test_set testState="Passed">
            <test
                lowerLimitMilliohms="0.00"
                name="Earth Bond 50Hz - BASE COVER"
                numTests="1"
                startConditions="StartKey"
                targetOutputAmps="25.0"
                timeHoldSeconds="2.0"
                timeRampDownSeconds="0.0"
                timeRampUpSeconds="0.0"
                type="EarthBond50"
                upperLimitMilliohms="200.00"
            />
            <test_result
                appliedOutputAmps="25.0"
                earthBondResistanceMilliohms="86.0"
                testDurationSeconds="1.90"
                testState="Passed"
                timeOfTest="2020-04-02T14:50:29"
            />
        </test_set>
        <test_set testState="Passed">
            <test
                lowerLimitMilliohms="0.00"
                name="Earth Bond 50Hz - BASE COVER"
                numTests="1"
                startConditions="StartKey"
                targetOutputAmps="25.0"
                timeHoldSeconds="2.0"
                timeRampDownSeconds="0.0"
                timeRampUpSeconds="0.0"
                type="EarthBond50"
                upperLimitMilliohms="200.00"
            />
            <test_result
                appliedOutputAmps="25.0"
                earthBondResistanceMilliohms="86.0"
                testDurationSeconds="2.00"
                testState="Passed"
                timeOfTest="2020-04-02T14:50:34"
            />
        </test_set>
        <test_set testState="Passed">
            <test
                lowerLimitMilliohms="0.00"
                name="Earth Bond 50Hz - BASE COVER"
                numTests="1"
                startConditions="StartKey"
                targetOutputAmps="25.0"
                timeHoldSeconds="2.0"
                timeRampDownSeconds="0.0"
                timeRampUpSeconds="0.0"
                type="EarthBond50"
                upperLimitMilliohms="200.00"
            />
            <test_result
                appliedOutputAmps="25.0"
                earthBondResistanceMilliohms="86.0"
                testDurationSeconds="2.00"
                testState="Passed"
                timeOfTest="2020-04-02T14:50:39"
            />
        </test_set>
        <test_set testState="Passed">
            <test
                lowerLimitMilliohms="0.00"
                name="Earth Bond 50Hz - BASE COVER"
                numTests="1"
                startConditions="StartKey"
                targetOutputAmps="25.0"
                timeHoldSeconds="2.0"
                timeRampDownSeconds="0.0"
                timeRampUpSeconds="0.0"
                type="EarthBond50"
                upperLimitMilliohms="200.00"
            />
            <test_result
                appliedOutputAmps="25.0"
                earthBondResistanceMilliohms="83.0"
                testDurationSeconds="2.00"
                testState="Passed"
                timeOfTest="2020-04-02T14:50:45"
            />
        </test_set>
        <test_set testState="Passed">
            <test
                lowerLimitMilliohms="0.00"
                name="Earth Bond 50Hz - CAPACITOR NUT"
                numTests="1"
                startConditions="StartKey"
                targetOutputAmps="25.0"
                timeHoldSeconds="2.0"
                timeRampDownSeconds="0.0"
                timeRampUpSeconds="0.0"
                type="EarthBond50"
                upperLimitMilliohms="200.00"
            />
            <test_result
                appliedOutputAmps="25.0"
                earthBondResistanceMilliohms="82.0"
                testDurationSeconds="2.00"
                testState="Passed"
                timeOfTest="2020-04-02T14:50:50"
            />
        </test_set>
        <test_set testState="Passed">
            <test
                arcDetect="0"
                lowerLimitMilliamps="0.00"
                name="HiPot 50Hz"
                numTests="1"
                startConditions="None"
                targetOutputKilovolts="1.50"
                testVoltageOutput="Back"
                timeHoldSeconds="10.0"
                timeRampDownSeconds="2.0"
                timeRampUpSeconds="2.0"
                type="HiPot50"
                upperLimitMilliamps="2.50"
            />
            <test_result
                appliedOutputKilovolts="1.49"
                leakageMilliamps="0.43"
                testDurationSeconds="14.00"
                testState="Passed"
                timeOfTest="2020-04-02T14:51:00"
            />
        </test_set>
        <test_set testState="Passed">
            <test
                lowerLimitMilliamps="0.05"
                name="Normal Connections"
                numTests="1"
                powerFactorLowerLimit="0.000"
                powerFactorUpperLimit="1.000"
                powerLowerLimitKVA="0.00"
                powerUpperLimitKVA="0.30"
                reversePolarity="0"
                startConditions="None"
                timeHoldSeconds="3.0"
                type="PowerLeakage"
                upperLimitMilliamps="0.50"
            />
            <test_result
                leakageMilliamps="0.10"
                powerAV="0.106"
                powerFactor="0.980"
                testDurationSeconds="3.00"
                testState="Passed"
                timeOfTest="2020-04-02T14:51:51"
            />
        </test_set>
        <test_set testState="Passed">
            <test
                lowerLimitMilliamps="0.00"
                name="Reverse Connections"
                numTests="1"
                powerFactorLowerLimit="0.000"
                powerFactorUpperLimit="1.000"
                powerLowerLimitKVA="0.00"
                powerUpperLimitKVA="0.30"
                reversePolarity="1"
                startConditions="None"
                timeHoldSeconds="3.0"
                type="PowerLeakage"
                upperLimitMilliamps="0.50"
            />
            <test_result
                leakageMilliamps="0.10"
                powerAV="0.106"
                powerFactor="0.979"
                testDurationSeconds="3.00"
                testState="Passed"
                timeOfTest="2020-04-02T14:51:56"
            />
        </test_set>
        <test_set testState="Passed">
            <test
                digitalOutputs="4"
                lowerLimitMilliamps="0.00"
                name="Single Fault Condition"
                numTests="1"
                powerFactorLowerLimit="0.000"
                powerFactorUpperLimit="1.000"
                powerLowerLimitKVA="0.00"
                powerUpperLimitKVA="0.30"
                reversePolarity="0"
                startConditions="None"
                timeHoldSeconds="3.0"
                type="PowerLeakage"
                upperLimitMilliamps="1.00"
            />
            <test_result
                leakageMilliamps="0.10"
                powerAV="0.007"
                powerFactor="0.756"
                testDurationSeconds="3.00"
                testState="Passed"
                timeOfTest="2020-04-02T14:52:01"
            />
        </test_set>
        <test_set testState="Passed">
            <test
                analogueInput2LowerLimit="1.62"
                analogueInput2Scale="22"
                analogueInput2Title="Flow"
                analogueInput2Units=" l/m"
                analogueInput2UpperLimit="5"
                digitalOutputs="9"
                lowerLimitMilliamps="0.00"
                name="Flow"
                numTests="1"
                powerFactorLowerLimit="0.000"
                powerFactorUpperLimit="1.000"
                powerLowerLimitKVA="0.00"
                powerUpperLimitKVA="0.30"
                reversePolarity="0"
                startConditions="None"
                timeHoldSeconds="15.0"
                type="PowerLeakage"
                upperLimitMilliamps="0.50"
            />
            <test_result
                leakageMilliamps="0.10"
                powerAV="0.105"
                powerFactor="0.977"
                testDurationSeconds="15.00"
                testState="Passed"
                timeOfTest="2020-04-02T14:52:06">
                <analogueInput2 name="Flow" units=" l/m" value="47.312" />
            </test_result>
        </test_set>
        <test_set testState="Passed">
            <test
                analogueInput1LowerLimit="0"
                analogueInput1Scale="37"
                analogueInput1Title="Vacuum"
                analogueInput1Units=" kPa"
                analogueInput1UpperLimit="0.4"
                digitalOutputs="8"
                lowerLimitMilliamps="0.00"
                name="Vacuum 10s"
                numTests="1"
                powerFactorLowerLimit="0.000"
                powerFactorUpperLimit="1.000"
                powerLowerLimitKVA="0.05"
                powerUpperLimitKVA="0.30"
                reversePolarity="0"
                startConditions="None"
                timeHoldSeconds="13.0"
                type="PowerLeakage"
                upperLimitMilliamps="0.50"
            />
            <test_result
                leakageMilliamps="0.10"
                powerAV="0.079"
                powerFactor="0.807"
                testDurationSeconds="13.00"
                testState="Passed"
                timeOfTest="2020-04-02T14:52:23">
                <analogueInput1 name="Vacuum" units=" kPa" value="0.904" />
            </test_result>
        </test_set>
        <test_set testState="Passed">
            <test
                analogueInput1LowerLimit="0"
                analogueInput1Scale="37"
                analogueInput1Title="Vacuum"
                analogueInput1Units="kPa"
                analogueInput1UpperLimit="0.36"
                digitalOutputs="8"
                lowerLimitMilliamps="0.00"
                name="Vacuum 30s"
                numTests="1"
                powerFactorLowerLimit="0.000"
                powerFactorUpperLimit="1.000"
                powerLowerLimitKVA="0.00"
                powerUpperLimitKVA="0.30"
                reversePolarity="0"
                startConditions="None"
                timeHoldSeconds="33.0"
                type="PowerTLeakage"
                upperLimitMilliamps="0.50"
            />
            <test_result
                leakageMilliamps="0.00"
                powerAV="0.079"
                powerFactor="0.802"
                testDurationSeconds="33.00"
                testState="Passed"
                timeOfTest="2020-04-02T14:52:39">
                <analogueInput1 name="Vacuum" units="kPa" value="0.904" />
            </test_result>
        </test_set>
    </appliance>
</session>
```

Now, using ElementTree, I can navigate through the xml elements as you'd expect, eg.

```
for child in test_set:
    print(child.tag, child.attrib)
```

returns the results:

```
test {'analogueInput1LowerLimit': '0', 'analogueInput1Scale': '37', 'analogueInput1Title': 'Vacuum', 'analogueInput1Units': 'kPa', 'analogueInput1UpperLimit': '0.36', 'digitalOutputs': '8', 'lowerLimitMilliamps': '0.00', 'name': 'Vacuum 30s', 'numTests': '1', 'powerFactorLowerLimit': '0.000', 'powerFactorUpperLimit': '1.000', 'powerLowerLimitKVA': '0.00', 'powerUpperLimitKVA': '0.30', 'reversePolarity': '0', 'startConditions': 'None', 'timeHoldSeconds': '33.0', 'type': 'PowerTLeakage', 'upperLimitMilliamps': '0.50'}
test_result {'leakageMilliamps': '0.00', 'powerAV': '0.079', 'powerFactor': '0.802', 'testDurationSeconds': '33.00', 'testState': 'Passed', 'timeOfTest': '2020-04-02T14:52:39'}
```

However, when I try and do a recursive function such as,

```
for test_set in root.findall("./appliance/test_set/[powerAV='0.079']"):
    print(test_set.attrib)
```

... the script will run without error, but returns no results. I'm a bit confused because I don't see how what I'm doing is any different to what the tutorial link is telling me to do, or various other internet sources for that matter.

I was hoping you internet geniuses could please help me out, thanks!

Comment: How to do recursive function? -> Just call the  function inside the same function

Comment: "the script will run without error, but returns no results." What result do you expect?